# Convert IImage to Structure

Tags: c#, emgucv

Is there a way to convert EmguCV IImage to EmguCV structure?

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> Frame;           // current frame from camera
Image<Bgr, Byte> Previous_Frame;  // previous frame aquired
Image<Bgr, Byte> Difference;      // difference between the two frames

double ContourThresh = 0.003; //stores alpha for thread access
int Threshold = 60; //stores threshold for thread access

private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    if (Frame == null) 
    {
        Frame = imageBox1.Image; //error
        Previous_Frame = imageBox2.Image; //error
    }
    else
    {
        Frame = imageBox1.Image;//error
        Previous_Frame = imageBox2.Image;//error

        Difference = Previous_Frame.AbsDiff(Frame); 
        Difference = Difference.ThresholdBinary(new Bgr(Threshold, Threshold, Threshold), new Bgr(255, 255, 255)); //if value > 60 set to 255, 0 otherwise 

        Previous_Frame = imageBox2.Image;
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

> Error 14  Cannot implicitly convert type `Emgu.CV.IImage` to `Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr,byte>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) d:\ece design project\aslt software\aslt software\seatplan.cs   917 25  ASLT Software

I am trying to get the difference between two image boxes, `imageBox1` and `imageBox2`.

- `imageBox1` is a processed image from the image captured by the camera while * `imageBox2` is an image from imageBox1 which are saved to the ms access database..

What I'm trying to do is to find an image in the database that matches to the imagebox1.. is what im doing here correct or you guys have a better option than using absdiff?

Comment: i added the compiler error through the snapshot sir, sorry if i've done it wrong...

Comment: done sir., thanks, and sorry for the mistake. :)

Comment: thanks for the edits.,
hope someone can help

Comment: Please do not post image of text.  Post text as text (which I see you have done separately - so you can remove the snapshop).

Comment: @Sabuncu.., done sir. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

after surfing some article i found out myself the answer for my own question.

this is what i did..

```
            Frame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(imageBox1.Image.Bitmap);
            Previous_Frame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(imageBox2.Image.Bitmap);
```

Comment: where i can find opencv dll's that are working with your code?